# Html2canvas not working highcharts to png doesn't work on Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, firefox, highcharts, html2canvas

We are using html2canvas.js and canvg.js (@version 2.0.1) and highcharts.js to download a chart into png image.

This works as expected in Chrome, however in IE and Firefox this not working.

Below are screenshots of the download in Chrome, IE and Firefox:

Chrome:
[Chrome image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN0Y9.png)

Firefox:
[Firefox image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkCYF.png)

**code:**

```
var svg = $('#previewImage');

html2canvas(svg, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
    var imgageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    download(imgageData, filename + '.png');
  }
});
}

function download(data, filename) {
  $('#previewImage').css('display', 'none');
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download = filename;
  a.href = data
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  a.remove();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? Please edit your answer and include  the relevant source code. Thank you.

Comment: Also please read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and eventually this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it will take a few minutes but will greatly improve your questions, and the answers you'll get ! :) Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: @NewToJS ,in console there is no error.

Comment: Maybe this [**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/willkoehler/1p81fbzs/) might be of some use to you.

Comment: @NewToJS, its working in firefox . in IE its not working..Thank you

Comment: @Venky, which version of IE do you use?

Comment: @KamilKulig, am using IE9 .

Comment: I launched the demo provided by @NewToJS on my machine with emulated IE9 and the error says that `window` object doesn't support `btoa` method. Official API confirms that: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp I'd recommend to find some workaround for that.